# Клик на nth-child(n) jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть структура

```
<div id="wrapper_answer">
<div class="answer">1</div>
<div class="answer">2</div><br><br>
<div class="answer">3</div>
<div class="answer">4</div>
</div>
```

нужно обработать каждый элемента `answer` 
Пробовал так, не работает

```
$('.answer:nth-child(3)').click(function(){alert("3"); })

$('#wrapper_answer:nth-child(3)').click(function(){alert("3"); })
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в `<br/><br/>`.

Указанный селектор выбирает элемент с классом `answer` являющийся третьим ребенком.
В текущей разметке - третьим ребенком будет `<br/>` соответственно селектор вернет `0` элементов.

Вместо [`nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) нужно использовать [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('.answer:eq(2)').click(function(){alert("3"); })
```

Важное отличие: `nth-child` считает с 1, `eq` с 0

Answer (score 2):

еще как вариант использовать `nth-of-type` вместо `nth-child`

```
$('.answer:nth-of-type(3)').click(function(){alert("3"); })
```